# How to find the sum of squares of $1\ldots N-1$ that add to a squared number $N^2$?

Tags: sums-of-squares

So here's a question my friend recently gave me and ever since I've been trying to solve it without much success:

There's a number $N$, and out of the set $U = \{1,2,3,\ldots,(N-1)\}$ we have to find a subset $S$ such that the sum

$\sum_{i\in S} i^2 = $
$\color{red}{N^2} ~: ~$(corrected what was assumed to be a typo : user2661923)

For instance if $N = 11$, $U = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$ has the solutions $S_1 = \{1,2,4,10\}$ and $S_2 = \{2,6,9\}$ because both $S_1$ and $S_2$ have square sums of $11$. Yet there's a caveat that **the solution having the largest square and the most number of elements is preferable**. In this case, $S_1$ is preferable because the largest element in $S_1$ is $10$ compared to that of $S_2$ which is $9$. Also $S_1$ has more elements than $S_2$ which satisfies our criteria.

I'm struggling to find a general deterministic algorithm that can find such subsets, for example what if $N$ is something like $50$? In that case there are many possible ways to build but subsets of squares that add to $50$ yet also to check these two criteria in conjunction proves to be somewhat of a challenge. I'm not sure if there is even such an algorithm, although I'll be happy to be proved otherwise.

What I've tried is that starting from $N-1$ in the set $U = \{1,2,\ldots,N-1\}$ I can count backward, but how do I choose if some number $i$ should be included in the solution set or not? For it may happen with extremely large sets that the way I would get a perfect sum of squares is dependent upon the specific numbers I choose rather than just make a decision based of the number I am currently standing on.

Comment: Don't you mean the that sum of the squares is $N^2$?  When $N=50$ we have to find as set $S\subset\{1,2,\dots,49\}$ such that $\sum_{i\in S}i^2=2500$, correct?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: It should be $\sum_{i \in S} i^2=N^2$

Comment: What's more important: having a larger term or having lots of small terms? Are we to interpret number of terms as a tie-breaker?

Comment: @davidlowryduda I was wondering the same thing.  I am also wondering if there is some way of showing that the group of terms with the largest term (**? must ?**) also be the group with the most number of terms.  Here, it would be interesting for someone to provide a *counter-example*.

Comment: Yes just clearing, sum should be $N^2$ not $N$

Comment: @davidlowryduda Glad you bought that up. According to the original question there is no detail besides what I've already mentioned. The question stated that in most cases the solution does contain $(N-1)^2$ more often and it also happens to be a larger number of elements. At this point I guess the question prefers more to have larger numbers in case of a tie in number of elements.

Comment: The link provided by saulspatz answers the question, doesn't it?

Comment: saulspatz link shows this problem is at worst NP-complete, but this problem as stated could be a special case in which a polynomial time algorithm exists.

Comment: @Weezy what's wrong with enumerating every subset ?  That is deterministic given the initial ordering of the elements.  Although it is probably inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

Before we start, let me point out that the set of numbers that cannot be
represented as a sum of distinct squares are finite (
[OEIS A001422](http://oeis.org/A001422)) and the largest element in this list is $128$. We are going to construct an algorithm based on this.

For any $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, let $[n,m] = \{ k \in \mathbb{Z} : n \le k \le m \}$.

For any $S \subset \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, let $f(S) = \sum\limits_{i\in S}i^2$.

By brute force, one can verify:

> For any $n \in [129,272]$, there is a $S \subset [1,11]$ such that $n = f(S)$.

For any $r \ge 273$, let $s = \left\lfloor \sqrt{r - 129}\right\rfloor$. It is clear $s \ge \sqrt{273-129} = 12$. Furthermore,

$$s \le \sqrt{r - 129} < s + 1 
\quad\implies\quad 129 \le r - s^2 \le 2s+ 129$$

Notice $s^2 - (2s+129) = (s-1)^2 - 130 > 0$. If $r - s^2 = f(S)$ for some $S \subset \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, the largest element in $S$ will be smaller than $s$. This will lead to $r = f(S \cup \{s\})$.

If $r - s^2 \in [129,272]$, we can express $r$ as a sum of distinct squares. If not, apply this procedure repeatedly to $r - s^2$ until we get one which falls between $[129,272]$. This will allow us to represent $r$ as a sum of distinct squares.

More precisely, construct a finite sequences of pairs $r_k, s_k$ by following rules:

1. Start from any $r \ge 129$. If $r < 273$, let $m = 0, r_0 = r, s_0 = 0$ and stop.
2. Otherwise, set $k = 1$ and let $r_1 = r$, $s_1 = \left\lfloor \sqrt{r_1 - 129} \right\rfloor$.
3. If $r_k - s_k^2 \in [129,272]$, set $m = k$ and stop.
4. Otherwise, let $r_{k+1} = r_k - s_k^2$, $s_{k+1} = \left\lfloor \sqrt{r_{k+1} - 129} \right\rfloor$. Set $k = k+1$ and repeat step 3.

At the end, we will have a bunch of distinct $s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_m$ (when $m > 0$) and $r_m, s_m$ such that the $r_m - s_m^2 \in [129,272]$. Lookup the $S \subset [1,11]$ with $r_m - s_m^2 = f(S)$, we will have

$$r = \begin{cases}
f(S), & m = 0\\
f(S \cup \{ s_1, s_2, \ldots, s_n \}), & m > 0\end{cases}$$

This means every $r \ge 129$ can be represented as a sum of $\ell \ge 1$ distinct squares:
$$r = \sum_{i=1}^\ell x_i^2 \quad\text{ with }\quad x_1 > x_2 > \cdots > x_\ell > 0$$
Notice $$x_1 \le \begin{cases}\sqrt{r - 129}, & r \ge 273\\ 11, & r \in [129,272]\end{cases} \implies \sum_{i=2}^\ell x_i^2 > 0$$

This implies $\ell > 1$ and we can strengthen above claim to:

> Every $r \ge 129$ can be represented as a sum of $\ell \ge 2$ distinct squares.

As a corollary,

> For $N \ge 12$, above algorithm produces a $S \subset [1,N-1]$ with $f(S) = N^2$.

For smaller $N$, not all $N^2$ can be expressed as a $f(S)$ for $S \in [1,N-1]$. By brute force again, one find the possible ones are $N = 5,7$ and all $N \ge 9$.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to provide a simple method (or algorithm) that will find all the solutions. Some of the solutions are easier to find than others.

This problem is simply a **problem of "how to decompose a square"** into squares. I will use the same example you gave to show how to derive the solutions.

**Decomposition of squares into a sum of squares**

$11^2= (1+10)^2 = (2+9)^2 = (3+8)^2 = (4+7)^2 = (5+6)^2$

$(1+10)^2 = 1^2 + 2*1*10 + 10^2 = 1^2 +20 + 10^2 = 1^2 +2^2 +4^2 +10^2$
Here $20$ was written as a sum of two squares: $20=2^2 + 4^2$ to get the final result (same as the one you listed).

$(2+9)^2= 2^2 +2*2*9+ 9^2= 2^2 + 6^2 + 9^2$

This is not the only solution since $36=6^2$ admit more than one decomposition into a sum of squares. For example $36= 16+ 16 +4=2^2 + 4^2 + 4^2$. You did not specify if the squares of the subset must be different. In the equation $(a+b)^2=a^2 + 2a*b + b^2$, it is not always possible to decompose $2a*b$ into a sum of $2$ squares but it can often be decomposed into a sum of $3$ squares or even a sum of $4$ squares or even more. It all depends on the restrictions you impose on the sum of squares, with or without repititions. $36=6^2$ can itself be decomposed into a sum of squares just like the one we are using for $11^2$. $36=6^2=(1+5)^2=(2+4)^2=(3+3)^2$.

$(3+8)^2= 3^2 + 2*3*8 + 8^2=3^2 +48 + 8^2= 3^2 + 4^2 +4^2 +4^2 +8^2$. In this case also we can decompose $48$ into $48=3*16=2*20+2*4=36+3*4$ sums which can easily be decomposed into squares $48=4^2 + 4^2 +4^2=(2^2+4^2) + (2^2+4^2) +(2^2+2^2)=6^2+2^2 +2^2 +2^2$. Again, it all depends on the restrictions imposed.

$(4+7)^2 =4^2 +2*4*7 +7^2=4^2 +56 + 7^2= 4^2 +(2^2 + 4^2 +6^2) + 7^2$. Here too, $56$ can be decomposed into more than one sum of squares.

$(5+6)^2= 5^2 +2*5*6 +6^2= 5^2 +60 + 6^2=5^2 +(2^2 +2^2 +4^2 +6^2) + 6^2$. And again 60 itself can be decomposed into sum of squares.

So I am not sure I understand where the complexity mentioned in some comments or answers comes from. The method above can provide the decomposition of any square into a sum of squares. The Wikipedia link talk about a subset sum problem as an NP-hard problem. I don't know if the decomposition of squares into a sum of squares can be thought of as an NP-hard problem.

Answer (score -1):

\begin{align*}
\bigg(\sum_{x=1}^{n}x^2\bigg)
&=\dfrac{n\big(n+1\big)\big(2n+1\big)}{6}
\\
\text{The $(n-1)$ sum minus $n^2$ should be zero}\\
\\
\bigg(\sum_{x=1}^{n-1}x^2\bigg)-(x)^2
&=\dfrac{(n-1)\big(n\big)\big(2n-1\big)}{6}
-(n)^2
=0\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
 (n-1)\big(n\big)\big(2n-1\big) -  6(n)^2 =0\\
n (2 n^2 - 9 n + 1)=0\\
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
n\in\bigg\{0, \dfrac{9 \pm\sqrt{73}}{4}  \bigg\}\\ 
 \\
\end{align*}

It appears that $S=U=\{0\}.\space $ There areno other integer solutions.

Comment: So you've shown that $S=U$ doesn't work, but what about when $S$ is a strict subset of $U$?